# $X=ABA^T$, X, A are matrix and need to solve matrix B by enforcing it as a diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, least-squares

$X=ABA^T$, 
X is a square matrix and A is rectangular matrix and I need to solve matrix B by enforcing it as a diagonal matrix.

For non-singular matrix we can write B as $A^+XA^{+T}$, but B gets to be non-diagonal matrix. How can I get B as diagonal matrix. (Eigen decomposition of X gives different values of A).

Comment: Is $X$ symmetric?

Comment: Yes X is symmetric ....

Comment: Then we could just use the spectral theorem and take an orthogonal $A$ so that $X = ABA^T$ is an eigendecomposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is to find the diagonal matrix $B={\rm Diag}(b)$ which minimizes $$f(B)=\| ABA^T- X \|_F^2$$ then neither of @frank's results will work.

Instead solve for the vector $b$ which zeros the gradient of the function, i.e. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=0$

$$\eqalign{
Y  &= ABA^T - X \cr
f  &= Y:Y \cr
\cr
df &= 2Y:dY \cr
   &= 2Y:A\,dB\,A^T \cr
   &= 2A^TYA:dB \cr
   &= 2A^TYA:{\rm Diag}(db) \cr
   &= 2\,{\rm diag}(A^TYA):db \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b} &= 2\,{\rm diag}(A^TYA) = 0  \cr
\cr
{\rm diag}(A^TABA^TA) &= {\rm diag}(A^TXA) \cr
\big((A^TA)\circ(A^TA)\big)\,b &= {\rm diag}(A^TXA) \cr
\cr
 b &= \big((A^TA)\circ(A^TA)\big)^+\,{\rm diag}(A^TXA) \cr
 B &= {\rm Diag}\Big[\big((A^TA)\circ(A^TA)\big)^+\,{\rm diag}(A^TXA)\Big] \cr
}$$
where colon denotes the inner/Frobenius product, i.e. $\,A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting property of the diagonalization operators
$$\eqalign{
 {\rm diag}(Z\,{\rm Diag}(y)\,W) = (W^T\circ Z)\,y \cr
}$$
where $\circ$ is the elementwise/Hadamard product, ${\rm Diag}(v)$ is a function which creates a diagonal matrix from its vector argument, and ${\rm diag}(M)$ creates a column vector from the diagonal of its matrix argument.

Applying this to your equation allows you to solve for $B={\rm Diag}(b)$ directly
$$\eqalign{
{\rm diag}(A\,{\rm Diag}(b)\,A^T) &= {\rm diag}(X) \cr
(A\circ A)\,b &= {\rm diag}(X) \cr
b &= (A\circ A)^+\,{\rm diag}(X) \cr
B &= {\rm Diag}\Big((A\circ A)^+\,{\rm diag}(X)\Big) \cr
}$$
where $M^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of $M$.

**Update**

The diagonalization of $X$ throws away some information, so here is another relationship that uses vectorization, and therefore preserves all of that information.
$$\eqalign{
 {\rm vec}(Z\,{\rm Diag}(y)\,W) = (W^T\otimes u)\circ(v\otimes Z)\,y \cr
}$$ the vectors $(u,v)$ are vectors all of whose components equal unity; the dimensions are such that the products $Z^Tu$ and $Wv$ are defined; and $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

Reference for this operation can be found in: *J Brewer, Kronecker products and matrix calculus in system theory, IEEE Transactions on circuits and systems, 1978.* [Link to pdf of paper from uta.edu](http://www.uta.edu/utari/acs/ee5329/lectures/Brewer%20Kronecker.pdf)

There the operation was defined in terms of the Khatri-Rao product, which results in $(W^T\otimes u)\circ(v\otimes Z)$.

Once again you can use this to solve for $B$
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(A\,{\rm Diag}(b)\,A^T) &= {\rm vec}(X) \cr
(A\otimes u)\circ(u\otimes A)\,b &= {\rm vec}(X) \cr
b &= \big((A\otimes u)\circ(u\otimes A)\big)^+\,{\rm vec}(X) \cr
B &= {\rm Diag}\Big(\big((A\otimes u)\circ(u\otimes A)\big)^+\,{\rm vec}(X)\Big) \cr
}$$ note that $v=u$ for this problem and the dimensions of $u$ are such that $A^Tu$ is defined.

Comment: If $X=ABA^T$ is a strict equality (i.e. not just in a least-squares sense), then either of the methods proposed by @frank will work. Since the matrix dimensions in the 1st method are smaller, I'd use that one.

Comment: thanks a lot @frank.

Comment: @lynn ... if this is not a strict equality ... (least squares) then what will be the solution be?